# Access VBA To Over Write File With No Prompt

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am using `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "qryExportData", strExportPath, True` to export an Access 2013 query to Excel with the save name/location hardcoded in the variable `strExportPath`

Is it possible to have Access VBA always over-write the file if it currently exists, or do I need to run a seperate VBA syntax to first check if the file exists, if it does delete, then save as?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this might get you what you want.  I didn't test it for your specific circumstance but... should work.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "qryExportData", strExportPath, True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Ah - I did not realize that a simple turning warnings off would cause the over write to take place with no prompt